# Почему "интрОверт", если "экстрАверт"?

Tags: орфография, заимствования

Может быть, вопрос у меня глупый, но мне всегда казалось, что такие однотипные слова, как "экстраверт" и "интроверт" должны писаться похожим образом. Почему же в одном случае А, а в другом — О?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А правда... Никогда не задумывался... И не уверен, что не написал бы машинально

Видимо - дань какой-то исторической заморочке. Прямого логического объяснения нет. 
Категорически не согласен, что "интро" единственно возможный вариант передачи латинского "intra". Во всяком случае, например, внутреннюю сеть называют с незапамятных времен называют интранетом.

Да и вообще.
http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%C8%ED%F2%F0%E0*&all=x

А вот  с интровертом тут что-то не так... Какая-то другая логика срабатывает.

http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%E8%ED%F2%F0%EE*

Рискну предположить -в порядке бреда, - что прослеживается разница в значениях: "внутренний" (интра) и "направленный внутрь" (интро). Не очень, правда,  последовательно...

---

Вообще-то четкий ответ дала Людмила... Я только высказал предположение.
И если ответ сочтен правильным, то я считаю себя обязанным о том сказать.

Comment: Вот меня тоже это озадачивает. Признаться честно, я до недавнего времени была уверена, что "интроверт" пишется через А.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что *экстр**а** - наружу, а* интр**о** - внутрь. В остальных языках аналогичная картина.

Answer (score 2):

Есть интра- внутри чего-то и есть интро-направленный внутрь. Интра-психическая ситуация- внутри индивидуальности Например,интрапсихический конфликт-(интра + греч. psyche – душа). Внутрипсихический, возникающий внутри психики. ; интро-психическая ситуация - социальная ситуация, когда индивидуум живёт среди людей, но взор устремляет внутрь себя.
Интроверт - происходит от нем. introvertiert «обращённый внутрь», а не находящийся внутри.

Comment: >Есть интра- внутри чего-то и есть интро-направленный внутрь
  
Людмила, я в общем-то об этом и говорил, но реализуется-то непоследовательно.  
Или Вы считаете, что тут есть какая-то система?

Comment: >introvertiert 
Интересно, почему тогда "интроверт", а не "интроферт", т.к., насколько мне известно, V в немецком произносится как "эф", без исключений. Из популярных примеров - марка Фольксваген (volkswagen)

Comment: >V в немецком произносится как "эф",   
  
Произносится-то оно в немецком, а в русский попало наверняка в *письменном* виде. И здесь правила не столько строги.   
  
Кстати, еще большой вопрос, как в немецком передаются и читаются  заимствования. Но это - к слову. Не по теме.

Comment: > а в русский попало наверняка в письменном виде

Такая версия возможна. Или заимствование было не из немецкого :-)